# Plupload: how to remove yellow highlight on delete event

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm using plupload plugin to create drag and drop form. I changed css to make plupload form look like form from my design. When i click on "delete" btn - thumbnail gets highlighted with yellow color. This is standart behavior of plupload plugin. **How can i change this color**?

It seems that yellow color is not created by css class. Its created with a js function (if i understand correctly). I tried to look inside plugins code to change this behavior, but can find right spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plupload uses JS to apply inline styles directly on the `.plupload_file` element upon delete. From my observation, it applies the inline styles `background-image:none; background-color: rgb(xxx, yyy, zzz); opacity: 0.xxx;` (where x,y,z values change dynamically until the element is removed from the DOM)

To override these styles, the simplest option is to utilize the CSS `!important` rule. For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="background-color: red;">
    The inline styles for this div should make it red.
</div>
```

We can fight that with this:

```
.myDiv {
   background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

The less graceful option would be combing through the source code to find where the yellow highlight is being applied, and modifying it.